# Simple Math quiz in phython

Tags: python

Being an **absolute beginner**, I'm facing some issues in my simple math quiz in python.

**First Issue:**
In my programme, the answer is stuck with option d only, i want to swap the correct option between the choice a-d every time.

**Second Issue:**
i declare a variable "score" and i try to increment it's value on each correct answer, but it's is not updating.

**Third Issue :**
I want to clear Previous question on selecting correct option and ask a new question.

My code is :

```
import random

def myFunction():
 score=0
 num1= random.randint(0,1000)
 num2= random.randint(1,1000)
 num2=num1
 if num1==num2:
   num2=num2+random.randint(0,50)
 print(num1, "+" , num2, "= ?")
 result=num1+num2
 option1=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option2=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option3=result+random.randint(1,25)
 d=result

 print("(a)", option1)
 print("(b)", option2)
 print("(c)", option3)
 print("(d)", result)
 value= input("Select the correct option \n  Answer:")
 if value=="d":
  print("Correct Answer...!!")
  score+=1                     #update score
  myFunction()
 else:
  result="d"
  print("Wrong Answer, Correct option is ","(",result,")")
  print("Your Score is : ", score)
  exit()

myFunction()
```

Comment: one issue at a time, please

Comment: It's not clear what you try to accomplish here.  You could explain  the program logic first, and show where you're stuck.  (Learn how to ask a question...)

Comment: `score` resets every time `myFunction()` is called

Comment: Why `num2=num1` followed by `if num1==num2:` near the beginning of the program (i.e. conditional will always be True since you set num2 to num1)?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish, it is not clear. Explain the main purpose of your program and where is it not working, so that we could help you.

Comment: Not sure the meaning of Third Issue.  Seems like you would be asking a new question with a right or wrong answer.  As an aside, its considered bad practice for a program to recursively loop in this form to get input from user (i.e. it will eventually crash with a **function error: “maximum recursion depth exceeded”**.

Comment: @DarrylG  when ever the program executed it asks for question on correct option it display next question below the first one in the console screen. my third issue is that when ever a correct option is selected, the previous question must be disappear from console screen. In other words, there will be only one question at a time on console screen.

Comment: @Majidkhan--does that mean the program should not end when the user enters the wrong answer?  I updated my answer so it clears the screen when running from a console.  If you're using Jupyter notebook we will need something slightly different to clear the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with following changes:

- You should use a while loop to iteratively get a response from user (otherwise you will eventually exceed recursion depth)
- It continues on wrong answers
- Stops on the first correct answer
- If you enters a blank line then it also stops (i.e. providing user a way to exit the program)

**Code**

```
import platform
import os
import sys
import random

def clear():
    '''
        Clears console
    '''
    system_ = platform.system()
    print('system_', system_)
    if system_ == 'Windows':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        # Linux or Mac
        os.system('clear')
        
def myFunction():
     score=0
        
    # Use while loop rather than recusively calling function
     while True:
        # Select two numbers
        num1= random.randint(0,1000)
        num2= random.randint(1,1000)

        if num1==num2:
            num2=num2+random.randint(0,50)
           
        print('clear the screen')
        clear()                               # Clear console
        
        print(num1, "+" , num2, "= ?")
        result = num1 + num2                  # the answer for sum
        option1 = result + random.randint(1,25)
        option2 = result + random.randint(1,25)
        option3 = result+random.randint(1,25)
    
        # options for sum
        options = [option1, option2, option3, result]   
        
        # Place options in random order
        random.shuffle(options)
        choices = "abcd"
        for choice, option in zip(choices, options):
            print(f"{choice} {option}")
        
        value= input("Select the correct option (or blank line to quit) \n  Answer:")
        
        while value and value not in choices:   # checks for blank line and if entry in choices
            print("Select letter from ", *choices)
            value= input("Select the correct option (or blank line to quit\n  Answer:")
            
        if value is None:
            # Blank line
            print(f'Final score was {score}')
            break   # done with while loop
            
        index = choices.index(value)

        if options[index] == result:
          print("Correct Answer...!!")
          score += 1                     #update score
          print(f"Your Score is : {score}")

        else:
          print(f"Wrong Answer, Correct option is ({result})")
          print(f"Your Score is : {score}")
           
myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code first stores the answer in a random option, and then the answer variable is given the value of the option, i.e a,b,c or d. I added the score variable as a parameter to the function and every time a correct answer is given the value of the parameter will be set equal to the score

```
import random


def myFunction(score=0):
 
 num1 = random.randint(0,1000)
 num2 = random.randint(1,1000)
 if num1==num2:
   num2=num2+random.randint(0,50)
 print(num1, "+" , num2, "= ?")
 result=num1+num2

 option1=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option2=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option3=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option4=result+random.randint(1,25)
 answer = random.randint(1,5)
 if answer==1:
   option1 = result
   answer = 'a'
 if answer==2:
   option2 = result
   answer = 'b'
 if answer==3:
   option3 = result
   answer = 'c'
 if answer==4:
   option4 = result
   answer = 'd'

 print("(a)", option1)
 print("(b)", option2)
 print("(c)", option3)
 print("(d)", option4)
 value= input("Select the correct option \n  Answer:")
 if value==answer:
  print("Correct Answer...!!")
  score = score + 1                     #update score
  myFunction(score)
 else:
  result=answer
  print("Wrong Answer, Correct option is ","(",result,")")
  print("Your Score is : ", score)
  exit()   

myFunction()
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does to solve the issues.

Comment: It first stores the answer in a random option, and then the answer variable is given the value of the option, i.e a,b,c or d. I added the score variable as a parameter to the function and every time a correct answer is given the value of the parameter will be set equal to the score.

Comment: Thanks for help... there is a little issue in the code, for first two or three questions it's running smoothly but later it shows error in the code..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want your code to work. But I edited your code as below. Once you entered wrong answer you will be out of from quiz.

```
 import random

def myFunction():
 global score
 num1= random.randint(0,1000)
 num2= random.randint(1,1000)
 # num2=num1
 if num1==num2:
   num2=num2+random.randint(0,50)
 print(num1, "+" , num2, "= ?")
 result=num1+num2
 option1=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option2=result+random.randint(1,25)
 option3=result+random.randint(1,25)
 d=result
 
 choice = [option1,option2,option3,result]
 random.shuffle(choice)

 print("(a)", choice[0])
 print("(b)", choice[1])
 print("(c)", choice[2])
 print("(d)", choice[3])
 value= input("Select the correct option \n  Answer:")
 if (value == "a" and d == choice[0]) or (value == "b" and d == choice[1]) or (value == "c" and d == choice[2]) or (value == "d" and d == choice[3]):
   print("Correct Answer...!!")
   score+=1                     #update score
 else:
  result= d
  print("Wrong Answer, Correct option is ","(",result,")")
  print("Your Score is : ", score)
  exit()
score = 0
while True:
  myFunction()
  print("Score : ", score)enter code here
```